# Best way to format currency in Yii gridview with no decimals

Tags: yii

Can Yii formatCurrency be used to format a currency value in cGridView with zero decimal places?

My current code is:

```
Yii::app()->locale->numberFormatter->'.'formatCurrency($data["'.$columnName.'"],Yii::app()->params->currency)
```

Which results in:

$50,000.00

And I want the result to be:

$50,000

Answer (score 1):

Same problem discussed in Yii forum. Here I added some points. Please check the relevant link.

This is due to your locale currency settings. Go and check your YII framework folder/i18n/data you will fix the problem there... Find your locale and fix it.

In ii18n/Cnumberformatter.php
change line 162

```
$value=round($value,$format['maxDecimalDigits']);
```

to

```
$value=number_format($value,$format['maxDecimalDigits'],'.','');
```

refer this forum.

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/21002-formatcurrency-broken/

Comment: thank you for this info. I should have been more specific in my question. I only want to remove decimals for a certain column in my gridview, not my entire application.

Comment: Then you have to write a separate function to do in view alone. For that, no need to change in core files.

Comment: You can write your own custom function in controller and pass the currency value to change as you need. Then you can call that function easily in gridview.

Comment: I was hoping to use Yii formatting but this seems simpler: `$newColumn['value'] = 'money_format("%.0n",$data["'.$columnName.'"])';`